# v7 CardView shadow gone on Android 5.0 with hardware acceleration disabled

Tags: java, android, drawing, hardware-acceleration, android-cardview

I noticed WebView in my app is very slow when hardware acceleration is enabled, so I disabled it in manifest application level.

The problem is, Android 5.0 implementation of support CardView require hardware acceleration to draw shadow, is any chance I can use Pre 5.0 logic on Lollipop devices?

Same code tested on versions 2.3, 4.3, 4.4 works fine, CardView shadow is gone on 5.0.
Example of xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/helper_view_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">
```

Comment: Use a custom library to get the shadow effect for all versions :D

Comment: Yeah, seems to be only way, It's a pity, I really enjoy using CardView

Comment: I ended up enabling Hardware Acceleration for 20+ API versions

Answer (score 0):

If the CardView in question is in a different Activity than the WebView, you can set acceleration to true just for the CardView Activity.

```
<activity
        android:name=".CardViewActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
</activity>
```